# Script shell, awk, lines and columns

Tags: shell, script, format, awk

Can you help me to format this datas in multiple columns ?

I have these datas on one column:

```
John
Patrick
6
4
5
7
1
2
40
15
MY CLUB
```

And would like to have :

```
John          6 5 1 40
Patrick       4 7 2 15
```

With fixed column because my actual script gives me:

```
John       6 5 1 40
Patrick       4 7 2 15
```

Comment: Maybe format the output of your script with `thescript | column -t`?

Comment: Please [edit] and post your actual script.

Comment: Hi Freddy, The column -t command seems to work but when i redirect my script to a file and display this text file in a ffmpeg loadtext argument i still have the same problem. Really it seems to be a format problem. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: @LivemediaLivemedia It looks like you need a monospaced font and maybe some more spaces/tabs to separate the values nicely.

Comment: The text a display seems to be right, i will test with this font you're talking about , come to you back.

Comment: hi Freddy ..... you're my saver, come to France i give you a kiss ! Monospaced font was the problem ....... it's one week i was turning around this problem .... Really thank you !

Comment: Finally when i use FFMPEG/loadtext as an argument with monospaced font it works fine but i also use another script with imagemagick / convert that creates an image with this text and convert dones not like the tabulations \t issues from my awk command script ....